# webdriver - how to capture screenshot on the assert statement passed

Tags: webdriver, screenshot, take

```
@Override
public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult tr) {


}
```

I add method onTestSuccess, but it takes screenshot only when the whole test passed, not assetion passed.

what can I do?